# What happened to Stan Lee after he drank the gamma soda?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, marvel, stan-lee, the-incredible-hulk-2008

In [The Incredible Hulk](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800080/), we see Stan Lee drinking a soda with Bruce Banner's blood in it:

He drops the bottle and we're told:

> ...it had more kick than he expected

But what actually happened to him?

Did he Hulk-out, even partially?

Is there any deleted scene or interview which sheds light on it?

Comment: That's how he became Watcher..

Comment: @ILoveYou3000 Beat me to it 

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't show the effects of consuming the contaminated drink in the movie but, in the script, the victim is a woman.

> KID (CONT’D) Mom? WHIP PAN:
>
> Mom is on the floor, her body in a spasm,
>   eyes rolled  back
>
> KID (CONT’D) MOM!!!
>
> INT. GENERAL ROSS’S OFFICE - DAY
>   GEN. T. ROSS at his desk. Lost in thought.  Snaps out of it when his
>   female aide, MAJOR CABOT,  puts some  forms on his desk. She moves him
>   through signing boring  requisition orders...
>
> CABOT ...and here’s
>   something a little more  interesting.
>
> He holds out his hand, not that
>   optimistic...
>
> she hands him a two  page fax..
>
> CABOT (CONT’D) Possible
>   gamma sickness. Milwaukee.   Woman drank one of these guarana sodas. 
>   Had more kick than she was looking for.
>
> ROSS Last three were
>   irradiated fruit, not  Gamma...
>
> CABOT Look at the spectrograph in that
>   path  report.  Even the FDA didn’t approve  that.  Whatever it was it
>   was  concentrated. Got less than a tenth of a  milliliter and it
>   almost killed her.

In the usual annoying and insufferable way of finding Stan Lee a part, they shoe-horned him into this scene and re-wrote it a little but he didn't "hulk-out", it just made him very ill.

At the time of the report to the general it is very clear that he didn't die as the line in the script maintains that it almost killed him.

There is nothing in the movie to confirm that he died and the screenplay is quite clear about the womans fate at the time of the report.

Comment: As amusing as it would have been to see Stan Lee hulk-out, I'm not sure that they could have done that and kept the tone they were going for in that scene.

Comment: -1 for "annoying and insufferable": that is just ranting, and not worthy of an answer.

Comment: It's not "ranting" - it is an opinion, A "rant" is defined as..."speak or shout at length in an angry, impassioned way." A couple of words in one sentance surely can't be said to be speaking or shouting at length.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this counts, but:

In Lego Marvel Super Heroes on PlayStation, the Stan Lee character can become a hulk with Stan Lee's head

Comment: You get an A for effort, but it doesn't count here. We're looking strictly at the Marvel Cinematic Universe.