# Was it not incredibly unlikely that Stan Lee would be the one to find this bottle?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk-2008, stan-lee

Stan Lee makes a cameo appearance in each film in the Marvel series but isn't it *incredibly unlikely* that he would have been the person that accidentally drank Bruce Banner's blood (the blood that accidentally tainted a bottle of energy drink)?

I can certainly see him appearing in many movies as an extra, but him drinking that particular bottle just beggars belief.

Comment: Um... are you asking if that's Stan Lee in the clip? Or if that's who the character is supposed to be rather than a random bystander?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, what are the odds of Stan Lee drinking that drink?

Comment: Between 0 and 100%. How can odds be determined for this?

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141611/is-there-any-significance-to-stan-lees-cameo-in-the-incredible-hulk

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109544/what-happened-to-stan-lee-after-he-drank-the-gamma-soda

Comment: i get what you're saying and have edited to try to make your question "pop" a bit more. It sleeps with the fishes though...

Comment: Let's start with the odds of getting a formula that converts a human into an undestructible green giant, and let's go down from there...

Comment: It was a joke from the start guys.

Answer (score 4):

Stan Lee wasn't playing [Stan Lee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wO0NsKFJ6gE&feature=youtu.be&t=2m56s) (the famous and noted comic writer) in this particular cameo, he was just playing the part of "*a man*".

> *“Here’s something a bit more interesting,” Sparr said. She held out a fax.   “Possible gamma sickness. Milwaukee. **A man** drank one of those guarana sodas. Guess it had a little more kick than he was looking for.”
>
>   “Where was the soda bottled?” Ross asked.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Phase One: The Incredible Hulk - Official Junior Novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22360823-phase-one)</sup></sub>

As such, his presence wasn't especially notable or coincidental

---

It might interest you to know that in the original script, the character who drank the poisoned bottle was just "A MOM", making her part the ideal stand-in for Stan Lee's cameo since it would save them having to create a new set and pay for five speaking extras just for a one-line joke.

> INT. KITCHEN - MIDDLE AMERICA - MORNING - WEEKS LATER
>
> A MOM is making a chaotic lunch for a bunch of seven year olds on
>   a playdate. Whole thing one camera shot: moving around, staying
>   with her, back and forth from fridge to table: a plate of apple
>   slices to get em started…popping the tops off some bottles of
>   juice and handing them around, stops to take a swig of her own
>   soda bottle sitting on the counter (we might know that bottle if
>   we got a close look at it, but we probably don't)… a plate of
>   chicken fingers and as they're dropped off we see some kids are
>   drinking… back for something to dip em in…
>
> <sub><sup>[Incredible Hulk - Edward Norton First Draft Screenplay (05-13-07)](http://pdfscripts.weebly.com/uploads/9/1/6/8/916864/incredible20hulk2c20the.pdf)</sup></sub>

Comment: Stan Lee [doesn't live in Milwaukee](https://www.quora.com/Where-does-Stan-Lee-live) :-)